# Adding / at the start and end of the asserted string in Response Assertion in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

**Assert given value:**

> "action":"GET /api/invoice_status","description":"[NO_AUTH] get
>   invoice statuses"

**Assertion failure message:**

> Test failed: text expected to contain /"action":"GET
>   /api/invoice_status","description":"[NO_AUTH] get invoice statuses"/

Comment: Could you please give a bit more information ??

Comment: @Captain0 I am asserting the text in Response Assertion as Text Response 'Contains' text. But after running the script it is adding the / back slash at start and end of the string. Due to this assert gets failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution by using the \ forward slash escape character.

Answer (score 2):

It is adding `/` slashes just to represent properly but it's not an issue. Cross verify your response after running the script, there might be some difference in the response and the text which you are passing in assertion. Also, there is no need to pass complete response in assertion, just pass some important text like success, passed (if present in response) or any other text available in your response and click on contains radio button inside `Response assertion`

Answer (score 0):

As per [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps)

> The Pattern can be either be:
>
> a “string” for “Equals” or “Substring” clauses
>
> a “Perl5-style” Regular Expression for “Contains” or “Matches” clauses

So if you choose "Contains" mode - JMeter treats pattern as [Regular Expression](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html). Either escape meta characters with a backslash - `\` or consider switching the Response Assertion into "Substring" mode instear.