# Why Response Assertion is not working in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, assertions

Here is my text response

```
<p class="equipment-left">
        <span id="p_lt_zoneContent_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl02_TireSearchResults_lblOriginalFrontEquipmentHeader">Original Equipment-Front: </span>
        <span class="equipment-num">
            <a id="p_lt_zoneContent_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl02_TireSearchResults_hypOriginalFrontEquipment" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;p$lt$zoneContent$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl02$TireSearchResults$hypOriginalFrontEquipment&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"></a></span></p>
    <p class="equipment-right">
        <span id="p_lt_zoneContent_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl02_TireSearchResults_lblOriginalFrontEquipmentCount">**We found <strong>@Count</strong> result(s) that fit your vehicle.</span>**
    </p>
</div>
<div id="p_lt_zoneContent_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl02_TireSearchResults_divOriginalRearEquipment" class="equipment" style="display:none;">
    <p class="equipment-left">
        <span id="p_lt_zoneContent_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl02_TireSearchResults_lblOriginalRearEquipmentHeader">Original Equipment-Rear: </span>
        <span class="equipment-num">
            <a id="p_lt_zoneContent_pageplaceholder_p_lt_ctl02_TireSearchResults_hypOriginalRearEquipment" href="javascript:__doPostBack(&#39;p$lt$zoneContent$pageplaceholder$p$lt$ctl02$TireSearchResults$hypOriginalRearEquipment&#39;,&#39;&#39;)"></a></span></p>
```

And here is my Assertion screenshot

[image]

Basically I am trying to assert that if the response contains the text "We found **@Count** result(s) that fit your vehicle." then fail that request but somehow it is always getting passed.

I tried with Text Response, Response Message and Document(text) option but it is not working with any of the option.

Am I missing something? Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Why Not is checked? Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43849721/jmeter-response-message-assertion-with-special-characters

Comment: Not is checked because I wants to fail the request when it contains the specified text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article:

> The Pattern can be either be:
>
> - a “string” for “Equals” or “Substring” clauses
> - a “Perl5-style” Regular Expression for **“Contains”** or “Matches” clauses

So given you set `Contains` mode JMeter treats your pattern as a [Perl-compatible  regular expression](http://www.pcre.org/). So you need to escape parentheses with a backslashes in your pattern in order to make it work as you expect like:

```
We found <strong>@Count</strong> result\(s\) that fit your vehicle.</span>
```

References:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions Meta Characters](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html#meta_chars)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Your answer make more sense hence accepting your answer.

BTW, thanks a lot for helping us for all the Jmeter related stuff. You have been very helpful for people like me who are just trying to learn Jmeter. Keep up the great work you are doing, cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by Changing the Pattern Matching Rules from Contains to Substring.

[image]